# Using color matching on two geotiff rasters datasets and exporting geotiffs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, layouts

I have one geotiff (tiff + tfw file) that serves as a basemap for a global zone. Then, I have several geotiffs, one for each zone of this big orthophotograph (50 zones in total).

I would like to match the colors of each of the zones geotiffs with the base geotiff. Each geotiff was imported as a raster dataset (File -> Add data and chose the geotiff data from the arcCatalog linked directory). Unfortunately, I cannot find the color correction tab in the raster dataset properties.

I can create a mosaic, but since the base geotiff is pretty big, I would like to know the better way to do this. I've searched through the whole ArcGIS doc/google and all docs were not applicable to my case (I'm using raster datasets, ont catalogs, mosaics or workspaces, and cannot find how to match the colors).

PS : Ideally, I would like to automatically create printable documents following a defined layout. This layout is made of 
 - a title and inset at the bottom, the inset made of the global geotiff with a red rectangle for the zone, with and north arrow and scale-bar, 
 - the detailed zoned with the zoom defined such that the clipping polygon fits the central area. 
For each of the 50 zones. I've added clipping polygons for each zone raster, and I would like to automatically create the documents with the big geotiff in an inset and the zone zoomed in. Is it easy to do using ArcGIS ? Again, I could not apply the solutions I've found.